# creating excel file from an c# application

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to create an excel file form c# application.

my code is as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


public class ExcelFileCreation
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    ***xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();***
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

    //and further lines of code.....
}
```

I am getting the following error in the highlighted line above as,

Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

please help me out of this problem!

Comment: There is good chance that searching for the error gives you details like - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Excel.Application` instead of `Excel.ApplicationClass`

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Update: 
You are referencing an interop assembly with "Embed Interop Types" set to `true`. According to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx) `Class` types contain metadata **and** code, while interfaces only contain metadata. It is safe to embed metadata but not anything that can potentially contain executable code.

Comment: can you please explain whats the difference between Excel.Application() and Excel.ApplicationClass()

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

with

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```